# TypeError when python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, oracle

I got a problem when '`python manage.py migrate`' after startproject and configr my database, is there any step I miss? the database creates two blank tables: `migrations, content_type`

centos7.5
python 3.4
django 1.11.15
oracle 18c

>

```
[root@localhost djtest]# python manage.py makemigrations

No changes detected

[root@localhost djtest]# python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 250, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1119, in execute_sql
    return self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)
  File "/usr/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py", line 245, in fetch_returned_insert_id
    return int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: have you tried to use the same command with eg. sqlite backend and `./manage.py migrate contenttypes` ?

Comment: @dydek i use mysql in the past, it worked all fine.

Comment: What permissions does the Oracle user have?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid grant dba,and all privileges to the user

Comment: Did you try this with Django 2.0?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i tried django 2.0.8, the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into a known bug [29759](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29759) which has to do with `cx_oracle` version 7.

You need to upgrade to django version 2.1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I install cx_oracle 6.4.1，and all work fine now.